# Error while constructing std::thread using 2 argumented function

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, sfml

I'm creating a simple game using SFML and I got this error:

> "std::invoke()": no matching overloaded function found
>
> Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'

while using following code:

thread function:

```
void  drawing(charact Hero, sf::RenderWindow window) {
while (window.isOpen()) {
    window.clear();
    window.draw(Hero.hitBox);
    window.display();
    }
}
```

thread declaration:

```
std::thread Draw(drawing, Hero, window);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sf::RenderWindow` is not copyable (due to inheritance of `sf::NonCopyable`), hence `drawing` cannot be called as-is. Add a reference or use (smart) pointers.

Comment: Did you change your 'drawing' function to receive it's argument by reference/pointer too?